# Is there any method to do lookup over the boost lock-free queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, lock-free

boost lock free queue is a new thing for me and I'm trying to use the boost lock free queue in my project. 
But find I can't lookup a element or iterate all the elements in the queue? If I use while(queue.pop(value)) to lookup a element, the queue will be empty.
Is there any method to lookup a element in the boost lock free queue?

Answer (score 0):

The conceptual model of a queue is `push`/`pop`. In this sense it's similar to stacks, except that the order might not be LIFO.

Iteration is not a feature, neither is lookup.

(Compare with the [`std::queue<>` container adaptor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue))

For more lockfree containers look at Intel TBB, MS PPL, **[LibCDS](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/)** etc.